# How Set a Variable in Go Depending on OS

Tags: build, go

I'm aware that I can name particular go files _windows.go, _linux.go, etc and that this will make them only compile for that particular operating system.

Within a file that doesn't have the go os specified in the filename, is there a way I can set a variable and/or constant within a file depending on the go os? Maybe in a case statement?

Comment: The GOOS solutions are good, but don't discount using a simple _<OS>.go file, even if it's just a line or two of constant declaration. It lets you detect at compile time any platforms you failed to implement (rather than at runtime like GOOS), and it lets you use constants rather than setting variables at runtime. GOOS can be useful, but the _<OS>.go stuff is there for good reason.

Comment: @RobNapier: I agree, I think that is a probably better choice than runtime.

Comment: Hey, just looked at your bio--does this mean StackExchange might be getting some services in Go soon? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`runtime.GOOS` is your friend. However, keep in mind that you can't set constants based on it (although you can copy it to your own constant) - only variables, and only in runtime. You can use an `init()` function in a module to run the detection automatically when the program starts.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "runtime"

func main() {

    fmt.Println("this is", runtime.GOOS)

    foo := 1
    switch runtime.GOOS {
    case "linux":
        foo = 2
    case "darwin":
        foo = 3
    case "nacl": //this is what the playground shows!
        foo = 4
    default:
        fmt.Println("What os is this?", runtime.GOOS)

    }

    fmt.Println(foo)
}
```

Comment: @tomwilde yeah, I know what it is, I was just surprised to see this as the host OS. It got me googling and I found and excellent article about it in the golang blog. As I suspected, they use it is a sandbox lightweight pseudo-vm - mocking FS, networking, etc. Very clever! http://blog.golang.org/playground

Comment: If it helps, you can also run your switch during initialization, since Go permits expressions at the toplevel: http://play.golang.org/p/48aXGUzH9u

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [`runtime.GOOS`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#pkg-constants).

> GOOS is the running program's operating system target: one of darwin,
>   freebsd, linux, and so on.

```
switch runtime.GOOS {
case "linux":
    fmt.Println("Linux")
default:
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOOS)
}
```